# How to set transitive = true for local .aar library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-gradle-2.0

I am using android cuckoo.aar local android library in my DemoApp project.

This cuckoo library also using many other libraries e.g( retrofit,recyclerview, rx-android, rx-java) through Gradle dependencies.

When I am importing this cuckoo library in DemoApp then I need to add all those dependencies in my demoApp that are used in library.

There is one solution is to make transitive = true in gradle. But it didn't help me.

Can someone help me right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to download transitive dependencies with a local aar file.

This file does not contains a `pom.xml` which reference all dependencies linked to this library, so adding `transitive = true` will do simply nothing.

If Cuckoo library is not hosted in a Maven repository, I'm afraid you will be obliged to load them manually in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: So  I have to host cuckoo library on maven repository That is only the options? @Bibu

Comment: It is one option, the other is to simply add in your `build.gradle` file all dependencies from Cuckoo library.

Comment: Yes choose second options and it solved my issue. Thanks for your answer. @Bibu